# STATA - multiple fixed effects in xtpqml or xtpoisson with multiple lags

Tags: regression, stata, fixed-effects-model, poisson-regression

I am trying to do quasi-Poisson regression and I found I can use xtpoisson or xtpqml in stata.

I am trying to do something like below code:

```
xtpqml abc var1 l.var1 l2.var1 l3.var1 l4.var1, fe i(states) i(week) cluster(states)
```

where I need to include the lags of var1 and fixed effects of states and weeks and clustering at the state level.

I am new to STATA and anyone can tell me how to use multiple fixed effects in xtpqml or xtpoisson with multiple lags?

abc is nonlinear, so I need to use a quasi-Poisson model and estimate standard errors
to allow heteroskedasticity. I want to use the coefficients on
the current and lagged var1 rates.

Comment: Have you considered Sergio Correia's [ppmlhdfe](http://scorreia.com/help/ppmlhdfe.html)? It fits Poisson pseudo-likelihood regression with multiple levels of fixed effects.

Comment: Yes, I tried, but isit the right way of doing that: ppmlhdfe abc var1 l.var1 l2.var1, l3.var1, l4.var1, fe i.states i.week, vce(cluster states). I am actually struggling with the right syntax